# UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf8' codec can't decode byte 0xcb in position 7: invalid continuation byte

Tags: python, unicode, utf-8

i get this error when i want to translate utf-8 to unicode,the error is :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\PyCharm Community Edition 2016.3.2\helpers\pydev\pydevd.py", line 1596, in <module>
    globals = debugger.run(setup['file'], None, None, is_module)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\PyCharm Community Edition 2016.3.2\helpers\pydev\pydevd.py", line 974, in run
    pydev_imports.execfile(file, globals, locals)  # execute the script
  File "C:/Users/Administrator/Desktop/new 1.py", line 64, in <module>
    view = changeListCode(train[1])
  File "C:/Users/Administrator/Desktop/new 1.py", line 33, in changeListCode
    a.append(i.decode('utf8'))
  File "C:\Anaconda2\lib\encodings\utf_8.py", line 16, in decode
    return codecs.utf_8_decode(input, errors, True)
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf8' codec can't decode byte 0xcb in position 7: invalid continuation byte
```

and my code is :

```
def readtrain():
    with open('Train.csv','rb')as csvfile:
        reader = csv.reader(csvfile)
        column1 = [row for row in reader]
    content_train = [i[1] for i in column1[1:]]
    view_train = [i[2] for i in column1[1:]]
    opinion_train = [i[3] for i in column1[1:]]
    print '训练集有 %s 条句子' % len(content_train)
    train = [content_train, view_train, opinion_train]
    return train

def changeListCode(b):
    a = []
    for i in b:
        a.append(i.decode('utf8'))
    return a




def segmentWord2(cont):
    c = []
    for i in cont:
        a = list(jieba.cut(i))
        c.append(a)
    return c


def transLabel(labels):
    for i in range(len(labels)):
        if labels[i] == 'pos':
            labels[i] = 2
        elif labels[i] == 'neu':
            labels[i] = 1
        elif labels[i] == 'neg':
            labels[i] = 0
        else: print "label无效：",labels[i]
    return labels


train = readtrain()

content = segmentWord2(train[0])  
view = changeListCode(train[1])
opinion = transLabel(train[2])
```

i copy the codes and file to notepad++,it shows utf-8.i saw other questions,but i don't get the solutions.and i can't use python 3.x now.

my file is like this:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TIJ0C.png)

i don't know how to upload my file.it's a  screenshot about my file,and my file is a csv.

Comment: Without seeing what data you are reading we can't really help here. Can you provide a hex dump of a file that reproduces the issue? See [How can I view the binary contents of a file natively in Windows 7? (Is it possible.)](//superuser.com/q/468456) on how to produce a hex dump.

Comment: The items in your `train[1]` list are not UTF-8-encoded if you get that error.  Not much more we can tell you without the content.